# R MySQL Problem while storing resultset into variable

Tags: r

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="",password="",dbname="",host="")
result<-dbSendQuery(con,"select * from employee") // employee table has id,name,dob,gender
```

When I execute second line the R crashes and a pop up window appears saying gui front end stopped working.

Am unable to understand what's happening. Could anyone explain me about this?

Comment: Can you add your r database package please as code (e.g. `library("RODBC")`) and also as a tag if it's available?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What is your `MYSQL_HOME` environment set to? Can you connect from the command line?

Comment: @StephLocke Although he should add it to the question, it is probably `RMySQL`

Comment: Looks like it, but there's also a GUI package called dbConnect on CRAN and just wanted clarification due to the GUI reference.

Comment: @nograpes am using windows 8 OS, Even from command Prompt i face same issue

Answer (score 0):

Something might be strange in db.
May I ask if you have tried `dbGetQuery` instead?

```
library(RMySQL)
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
ch <- dbConnect(drv,dbname="xyz", user="zyx", password="verysecretsecret")
sql <- paste('select * from employee', sep='')
result <- dbGetQuery(ch,sql)
```